# Web api searches for library files in wrong path

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using external library [NTextCat](http://ntextcat.codeplex.com/) for text language recognition which loads external `.txt` files that hold definition of languages. Files are loaded at runtime.
I've already used this library sucessfully in few projects: ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC and WinForms.

Here is how constructor looks in which files are loaded, I am using empty constructor:

```
 var languageIdentifier = new LanguageIdentifier(); // Empty constructor uses default \LM fodler
 var languageIdentifier = new LanguageIdentifier("path to files"); // Overload which takes different path to files
```

I already copied said folder to every project in solution including every bin folder, with no luck.

I get exception like:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\LM\'.A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Why does it keep searching that path?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that you have to map path while on web, so:

```
  var path = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "LM");
  var languageIdentifier = new LanguageIdentifier(path);
```